# What is the group/party size in Lord of the Rings Online?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

How large of a group can you play Lord of the Rings online with? Is it a group/party based game?

I play PC games with a group of 4-5 people and we are looking for something we can all play together online.  Does LOTR Online fit that criteria?

We currently play Guild Wars, but we are running out of content there, and have been thinking of something different to start playing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum group size in LOTR: Online is 6 players.

I started playing LOTR after playing Guild Wars and I feel like it's very group oriented. The quests are all varying degrees of difficulty; some of them are recommended only for parties. The guilds that I've come across in LOTR are very active and friendly. There's a ton of content apart from the main storyline and new content gets added on a weekly basis. It should keep your interest for quite a while.

Comment: On top of what Spugsley has mentioned, there are also raids which consists of 2 to 4 Fellowships. There are also three-men quests/instances, and recently, many of the earlier instances have been refactored so that they scale up to how many people are in your group.

Answer (score 2):

You can group up to 24 players. A group have the maximum of 6 players and a raid of 24 players. The grouping is seperated into 4 categories:

- small group (3 players)
- groups (6 players)
- raid (12 players)
- large raid (24 players)

You can complete most of quests while in group and within up to normal group size (6 or lower) without any backdraw. The exception are raid dungeons and quests and some instanced dungeons you have to complete in small group size (3 or lower). Most instanced dungeons are designed for normal group size (6). Btw. there is NO scaling. You should go into the dungeon with the suggested group size. There IS a level scaling for some dungeons as the "Great Barrows" dungeon.

Comment: @fireDude67: Sorry i have to disagree (while its getting now quite difficult to tell the difference between skirmish and instance).

Skirmishes are accessed via skirmish tab and have scaling for group size, level and a tier selection (T1 - T3).

Instances are accessed via instance tab and have a fixed group size and CAN HAVE a level scaling and CAN HAVE a tier selection (currently only T1 and T2). Examples are the instances like "Great Barrows", "Annuminas", "Helegrod"  or the new instance cluster of the lastest update (like "Süre-Surma", "Hall of Night").

Comment: That's what I said. Or, rather, that's what I intended to say.

Answer (score 1):

Max Fellowship (group) size, is 6

However:

- Small Fellowship = 3
- Full Fellowship = 6
- Half-Raid = 12
- Full-Raid = 24

However, do note that some quests, if done without a fellowship when a fellowship is required, will give you Inspiration. Inspiration gives you a massive health boost (300%), a massive power boost (250ish%), +250% damage, +3000 regeneration rate. Basically, it's a "God Mode" because you are practically invincible. Some quests are: Vol 1, Bk 2, "The Red Pass", All of Vol 1, Bk 3. Those are the Inspiration quests I have done. There are many more.

Check the lorebook/lotro-wiki.com for more.

**Edit:** Please note that Skirmishes, can be scaled from Solo to Half-Raid. 
**Edit:** Also note that Private Instances can be scaled for just the LEVEL, but not all of them, like GA.